# Incorrect output when printing an integer array

Tags: c

I wanted to create a general print array function. This function would print array elements based on the data type.

```
#include "utilities.h"

//type : 0 ->int
//     : 1->char
void print_array(void *arr, int length, int type){
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        switch(type) {
            case 0:
                printf("Integer %d  %d\n", (int*)(arr+i));
                break;
            case 1:
               printf("%c \n", (char*)(arr+i));
               break;
            case 2:
                printf("%s \n", (char*)(arr+i));
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("%x \n", (int*)(arr+i));
                break;
            default:
                printf("Format not supported yet. %d \n",type);
                return;

        }
    }
}


void test_print_array(){
    int int_arr[3] = {0,1,2};
    print_array(int_arr,3,0);

}

int main(){
    test_print_array();
    return 0;
}
```

Output I am getting is

Integer -486474964

Integer -486474963

Integer -486474962

Instead of 0,1,2

I also tried using arr[i] instead of (int*)(arr+i) but I am getting compiler errors on that.

Comment: Post your compiler errors/warnings.  Example: Review `printf("%c \n", (char*)(arr+i));`.  `%c` expect a char` or `int`, not a pointer.

Comment: You're not dereferencing the pointers, and you're doing the pointer arithmetic on the uncast pointer and casting the result.  Try eg. `((int *)arr)[i]` instead of `(int*)(arr+i)`

Comment: You also might want to consider using an enum for the types...

Comment: You're using a compiler that allows pointer arithmetic on `void*`, like gcc. Those that do, consider the distance between "elements" to be 1.

Answer (score 3):

You are using pointer arithmetic on `void*` type, whose size is unknown. You must cast the pointer *before* doing the arithmetc, but it is clearer to use array notation anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(void *arr, int length, int type){
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        switch(type) {
            case 0:
                printf("int %d\n", ((int*)arr)[i]);
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("char %c\n", ((char*)arr)[i]);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("string %s \n", ((char**)arr)[i]);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("hex %X\n", ((unsigned*)arr)[i]);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Format not supported yet. %d \n",type);
                return;

        }
    }
}

void test_int_array(){
    int int_arr[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    print_array(int_arr, 3, 0);

}

void test_char_array(){
    char char_arr[3] = {'x', 'y', 'z'};
    print_array(char_arr, 3, 1);

}

void test_str_array(){
    char *str_arr[3] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    print_array(str_arr, 3, 2);

}

void test_uns_array(){
    unsigned uns_arr[3] = {26, 27, 28};
    print_array(uns_arr, 3, 3);

}

int main(){
    test_int_array();
    test_char_array();
    test_str_array();
    test_uns_array();
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
int 0
int 1
int 2
char x
char y
char z
string one 
string two 
string three 
hex 1A
hex 1B
hex 1C
```

Answer (score 0):

A general print array function is prone to *undefined behavior* (UB) unless the data reference is aligned properly and of a valid value.

Having said that, try

```
//printf("Integer %d  %d\n", (int*)(arr+i));
//              vv-------- print a `%`
printf("Integer %%d  %d\n", ((int*)arr)[i]);
//                          ^---------^ form a `int *` and then use [i]
```

Adding `i` to a `void*` is UB.  Cast the `void *` pointer *first* to the desired pointer type, then use the index `[i]`.

Comment: utilities.c:11:47: error: operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
                printf("Integer %d \n", (int*)arr[i]);

Comment: @user968000 Your comment does not include the `()` of the answer. Use `((int*)arr)[i]` to insure proper evaluation.  `(int*)arr[i]` is like `(int*)(arr[i])` which is invalid.

Comment: works now : printf("Integer %d \n", ((int*)arr)[i]); thanks